# Most effective way to add custom script to /bin? & best practices

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, path, export

Most effective way to add custom script to `/bin`? I know that I can do:

- symbolic-link(but I don't understand how to undo this or clean it up, even after researching)
- `alias xxx="/path/to/script"`
- or add my repo folder to path: `export $PATH=~/gitClones/myGit/Bug-Bounty-Enumation-w-ZSH/:$PATH`

I'm wondering what are best practices for this?

Incidentally, none of those are working for me yet:

```
export $PATH="/home/nate/gitClone/myGit/Bug-Bounty-Enumation-w-ZSH":$PATH
export: not valid in this context: /home/nate/go/bin/:/home/nate/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

Comment: For variable assignment, do not use a `$` on the left-hand side: `PATH="$new_path:$PATH"` -- no need to `export` it, it's already exported.

Comment: I would add the directory to my PATH, but  you have to do this in both bash and zsh.

Comment: If you want to install it to a central location, use `/usr/local/bin` -- that is intended for programs local to your computer. `sudo install -vp -t /usr/local/bin /path/to/your/script`

Comment: That sudo install... is REALLY nice! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## some caveats to your question

Firstly, `alias`es and adding to the `PATH` only effect the shell you have configured.  There are central system files that will effect multiple accounts, but even then you're limited to that flavor of shell and you haven't really added anything to `/bin`.

Secondly, as glenn jackman pointed out your `export` doesn't work because of the `$` on the left side of the equals.  The `$` means substitution and so it doesn't make sense to assign to it in the shell, even though other languages like Perl would let you do this.

## install via symlinks

So, that leaves us with the symlink option.  It would be more correct to put this in `/usr/local/bin/`.  I'm going to do this for a script called `~/Documents/stackexchange/example`.  To create the symlink I would:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s ~/Documents/stackexchange/example .
```

To clean it up:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/example
```

And to verify that we cleaned up:

```
$ ls /usr/local/bin/example 
ls: /usr/local/bin/example: No such file or directory

$ ls -l ~/Documents/stackexchange/example 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 chicks  staff  26 Aug 29 16:36 /Users/chicks/Documents/stackexchange/example
```

I've included the $ to indicate the prompts and so you can see that the `ls` shows that the original file is still there while the symlink is gone.

## best practices

Using symlinks in this way would be a best practice and it is similar to how homebrew installs things.

It would also be a best practice to put the code in `/opt/$PROJECT_NAME/bin` and symlink it from there.

Root should own the files in `/opt`.  If you keep the project in you home directory I would keep the files owned as the user so you can work with them easily.